# What does -wise mean in the context of feed forward networks?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I try to get the exact synonym of the *-wise* part in the following sentence: *I believe it's position-wise feed forward network, a type of position-wise.*

Comment: This is too short a fragment to paraphrase. If you [edit] the question to provide a whole paragraph alonmg with some idea of what "position-wise" means is a feed forward network we might be able to help.

Answer (score 3):

> [**-wise**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-wise), suffix
>
> 3. in the matter of; with regard to
>    *This morning looks promising, weather**-wise**.*

So a "position-wise feed forward network" is a network which feeds forward with regard to position, as opposed to some other parameter. What exactly this means is not clear without more context.